# In-universe explanation for Walter Donovan's foolish decision?

Tags: indiana-jones, the-last-crusade

"I am not a historian," says Donovan, right after he hears the grave consequence of drinking from the wrong cup. Then, he promptly drinks from the cup that Schneider selects. I find this latter action at odds with Donovan's earlier characterization and earlier events in the story:

- He's a collector of rare artifacts; he's done *some* reading about the Grail; he's been in touch with Grail scholars (Jones Sr., Schneider).
- There is a drawing of the Grail in Jones Sr.'s diary: [image]
  which looks nothing like the cup that Elsa selects; Donovan and co. have the diary in possession at length
- He's a cunning strategist

Is there an in-universe explanation for Donovan's action? For instance, why doesn't he force Elsa to drink first from the cup she chooses?

Comment: They call it the [Idiot Ball](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IdiotBall).  **Warning: TV Tropes.** (That said, I doubt the magic would let you force someone else to drink against their will, or to force them to give you the true Grail after they have discovered it.  Otherwise anyone could go in with a whole bunch of people and find the true Grail by process of elimination.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He is also power-hungry, blinded by greed, and bound up in the ideology of superiority.  Elsa is a woman, and (by the ideology of Donovan's fellow travellers, which appears to have rubbed off a bit) thus inferior.  Moreover, by that same ideology *God* would not have an inferior cup.

Add to that the fact that he has no reason for thinking that Jones Senior's drawing is accurate.  You missed the very next sentence uttered by Donovan: "I have no idea what it looks like."  He has no reason to think that Jones Senior has any idea, *either*.  The drawing in the diary could be little more than a product of Senior's fancy.

That he is blinded by avarice and arrogance is the conventional wisdom.

Lester D. Friedman of Northwestern University has a slightly different one to offer:  He is *not* blinded to his own lack of expertise, but he *does* arrogantly delegate the task to an expert whom he views as subordinate to him and is blinded to the risk of doing so.  He has no reason to distrust Schneider, and Schneider takes advantage of that in order to kill him and thereby take the power for her own.

There is some support for this in the novelizations, which say

> Donovan stared in bewilderment at the collection of chalices before him.  But Elsa's eyes lit up instantly.

Friedman points out in support of this that she selects the chalice quickly and only after a cursory inspection, which is "hardly the act of a well-trained and prudent archaeologist", that she then exchanges a knowing look with Jones Junior, that she does not react to Donovan screaming after he drinks, only reacting when his skeleton falls onto her, and that she even outright says "It would not be made out of gold.".

In other words: "He chose poorly." *actually* means that he chose to trust Schneider, who deliberately killed him in return.

Not everyone agrees on this, of course.  But whilst they differ about Elsa they do agree that *Donovan's* motivations are straightforward and apparent: lust for power, selfishness, and arrogance.  And that he is blinded by them in *some* way or other, whether that be in choice of cup or choice of expert to trust.

## Further reading

- Lester D. Friedman (2010).  "Spielberg's Action/Adventure Melodramas". *Citizen Spielberg*.  University of Illinois Press.  ISBN 9780252091292.
- Joe Posnanski (2014-07-16).  *[He chose … poorly](http://joeposnanski.com/he-chose-poorly/)*.  joeposnanski.com.
- [In the Indiana Jones and the Last crusade, did Elsa betray Donovan?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139106/)

Comment: Neat answer. You get a tick!